# How to call URL in swift which contain square bracket[ ]

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to call a web service which contain **square brackets[ ]**.
But I don't know How do I call that api.

URL is shown below
http request method is GET.

> https:"YOUR URL"/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=**(txtFldSearch.text!)**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like

this is what I tried

```
@objc func getHintsFromTextField(textField: UITextField) {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: "https:"YOUR URL"/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%\(txtFldSearch.text!)%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like")!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in

            // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
            guard error == nil else {
                print ("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
            guard let content = data else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }

            // serialise the data / NSData object into Dictionary [String : Any]
            guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Not containing JSON")
                return
            }

            print("gotten json response dictionary is \n \(json)")
            // update UI using the response here
        }

        // execute the HTTP request
        task.resume()
}
```

What's the right way to do this?.Please help. I am not able to call this api.

Comment: take all values in variables and after concat make the URL or you can use **let URL = "\(value1)" + "\(value2)"** and so on.

Comment: @Nikunj Kumbhani- can you please explain more?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani can't understand what is your actual problem. You need to create a string with that format? if so try `"https:YOUR URL/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=\(txtFldSearch.text!)&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like"`

Comment: @ Nikunj Kumbhani - it didn't work.

Comment: How did you solve that?
Does final url shows proper formatted url or change brackets to something like %5B%5D ?